# Passing command ling arguments to juby in rbenv

Tags: java, jruby, rbenv

I'm using rbenv with the latest version jruby. I'm trying to set the memory limit as well as pass some additional command line arguments to all jruby operations.

I tried `set JRUBY_OPTS=-Xms128m-Xmx256m-Xcompile.invokedynamic=false-J-XX:+TieredCompilation-J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1-J-noverify-Xcompile.mode=OFF`, but I don't think took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `-J` in front of your memory directives:

```
JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Xmx256m -J-Xms128m..."
```